# Complete table with another table which has same id

Tags: mysql, sql

i have two table "product" and "sales". product have "id,Name,price" and sales have "id,pro_id" .
in product table save all products with unique id, and in sales table save all sales product with id of product in "pro_id".
i want a sql which can report a table sales with full data of product info.

for example report have "pri_id,Name,Price" columns.

**sample:**
product:

> id--------Name------price
>  1---------RAM-------300
>   2---------CPU-------400

sales:

> id---------pro_id
>  1---------2
>  2---------1
>  3---------2
>   4---------2
>  5---------1

result of report :

> pro_id----Name------price
>  2---------CPU-------400
>   1---------RAM-------300
>  2---------CPU-------400
>   2---------CPU-------400
>  1---------RAM-------300

Comment: if thats what you want, perhaps you should attempt writing a SQL statement.

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to achieve? As the question is currently worded, it's hard to understand what what you're asking.

Comment: It's better to try something and then asking here, and tell us what have you done to solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> SELECT pro_id,name,price FROM  product JOIN sales ON sales.pro_id =
>   product.id